# Getting errors while trying to reindex using ssh in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento 1.8.1.0 on a dev server with php version 5.3.3.When I try to reindex from shell I am getting following errors

```
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_long_arrays' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
```

I am having same version of php on my production server but I do not get these errors there.I have display_errors Off on both the dev and the live server.

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: You may have `display_errors` set to `0` on production but not on your sandbox.

Comment: @neubert I have display_errors Off on both the dev and the live server.

Comment: try to  add this to php.ini, if it works then you should be doing the same for the other two "php_value register_long_arrays Off
"