# After moving a Magento site to the development server search results redirect to the live site

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have moved alive site to the development server. I followed all the step to move the Magento site to new server.Every thing is working well except when I search nay products it redirect the user to the live site.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know nothing about Magento, but there must be some kind of configuration to the search tool where you specify the search results page, and if you did migrate from live to dev I presume you also migrated this info... so you should just update this configuration on dev environment...

Comment: check if u have hardcoded the dev url path in your code.

Comment: Using some third party search like Celebros? That's going to just be the way it is as those type searches have their search results locked into the live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On live site searchspring extension was used for the search functionality.Because of that the search results on stage site were also coming from live site.

Answer (score 0):

So what steps did you follow?

Have you reindexed your data and changed your base url's to the development environment?

Comment: What issues are you facing? They can be related

Comment: When I try to reindex using shell commands I am getting

PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_long_arrays' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546442/getting-errors-while-trying-to-reindex-using-ssh-in-magento